# Invoke log4net appender only for Warn and above

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

Quiet new to log4net appender.

I have created a new log4net appender which I would like to get called only if the level is Warn or Fatal or Error.

I tried below but doesn't seem to be working i.e. it gets called for Info as well.

```
<root>
      <priority value="ERROR" />
      <appender-ref ref="MyBrandNewAppender" />
      </root>
```

Also what's the difference between above and below:

```
<logger name="bla" additivity="false">
      <level value="ERROR" />
      <appender-ref ref="MyBrandNewAppender" />
    </logger>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the root tag you are using priority.

```
<priority value="ERROR" />
```

I am using level which works for me.

```
<level value="ERROR" />
```